# Can I stop MSBuild deploying application if unit tests fail?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, tfsbuild, webdeploy

So I added automatic deployment to my CI build with the following MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:DeployIisAppPath="myWebsite/myAppname"
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=myServer
/p:username=myDomain\myUserName
/p:password=myPassword
```

Obviously names have been changed to protect the innocent  :)

My problem is this deploy runs before the unit test run.  If the build fails because the unit tests fail, the build is still deployed to the web server.

How can I prevent deployment in the event of the unit tests failing?  Is there a smarter way of doing this using VS2012 and TFS2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have my build simply spit out the WebDeploy package (e.g. DeployTarget=Package), then have an InvokeProcess at the end of my workflow that runs a powershell script to do the actual deployment.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the default TFS build template, there is a section to Fail the build on test failure which is set to False by default.  Setting this to true may do exactly what you are asking.

In the build definition:
1. Go to Process tab
2. Expand Basic section
3. Expand Automated Tests
4. Expand Test Source
5. Change value on "Fail Build On Test Failure" field.

Comment: This will indeed mark the build as failed but the deployment will still be triggered.

Comment: This doesn't stop the build from being deployed.